# How to kill all processes of the same name but keep the latest one running?

Tags: awk, ps

I've seen [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/71360/find-and-kill-old-processes) but I can't quite figure out how to kill all processes of a given name but keep the most recent one running.

So for example, this will show me the running processes:

```
$ ps -eo pid,etime,comm | grep maya.bin
23752       10:40 maya.bin
23841       12:04 maya.bin
23891       14:46 maya.bin
```

Somehow, I would need to filter out the PIDs `23752` `23841` (but not `23891`) and kill those.

If I could just figure out how to find those PIDs, presumably via awk, I could kill via e.g.

```
ps -eo pid,etime,comm | awk ??? | kill -9
```

or

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 'maya.bin' | awk ??? )
```

Is this possible using awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to select the first word and then all but the last row. You can do that with

```
awk '{ print $1 }' | head -n -1
```

The total command would then be

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 'maya.bin' | awk '{ print $1 }' | head -n -1)
```